# Java JFilechooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I would like to be able to control the appearance of the `JFileChooser`. In particular I would like to save how the `JFileChooser` was displayed when it was last shown. I would like to save whether it was used in details/list view and which column (eg, size or date modified) the lists were sorted.

I know there is a lot of questions about `JFileChooser` but I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

Thanks

**EDIT:** it was suggested as an answer, but keeping a reference of the filechooser is not suffient, as I want to persist the settings across many times that I run the application

**EDIT:** for example I usually want to open the most recent file I have downloaded, so I want to sort by date modified and display in detail view

Comment: *"most recent file I have downloaded,.."* As a user, I would prefer to be offered a `JMenu` containing a list of `Recent Files` (or similar).  `File` objects can also be serialized.

Comment: @Andrew, I appreciate you suggestion. I usually download a file or save an email attachment and need to import it into my application, so it cannot be in Recent List.

Comment: *"..so it cannot be in Recent List."* I do not understand that comment.  The `File` can be added to a list of recent files when it is first imported/opened.

Comment: I usually save attachments to the same folder. I already have that folder opening by default when I am importing to my application, but I would like for the fileChooser to display that folder in detail view and sorted by Date Modified

Comment: I still do not quite understand how any of what you said is simpler than a 'recent files' list, but if you *must* go that way, I suggest side-stepping `JFileChooser` completely and develop a custom file chooser that allows the details you want to be stored.  You might want to start that process with the code shown on [File Browser GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui).

Comment: Nice File Browser, +1 in that thread.

The files that I want to import arrive by email. I save all of the to the same folder. Over time the accumulate in that folder. When a new email comes, I save the attachment, and want to import that file from that particular folder. Therefore, I do not want to search whole directory by the name of the new file, I just want to have them sorted by Date Modified - meaning the new file will be easy to find (either top or bottom of list).

Once I select file to import, it gets processed &stored in database. From DB I have recently opened "tools" implemented

Comment: this is just 1 application, but saving the state of the filechooser could have other uses, for example your file explorer in your OS stores which view you had in a folder and how items were stored

Comment: @AndrewThompson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1924/discussion-between-leon-and-andrew-thompson)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a reference to it and only construct it once.  It should open on subsequent occasions looking pretty much like it did when the user disposed it.  You would need to take extra steps to restore the **location** of the file chooser.

---

#### Persisting between runs.

There are a number of ways of storing the data between runs (e.g. a properties file, XML, `Preferences` etc.).  This is the quick'n'dirty way to achieve it.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class SerializeMyChooser {

    static private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    static File serializedChooser = new File("chooser.ser");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JButton showChooser = new JButton("Open File");
                showChooser.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if (fileChooser==null) {
                            if (serializedChooser.exists()) {
                                // use the resialized form
                                try {
                                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                                        new FileInputStream(serializedChooser));
                                    fileChooser = (JFileChooser)ois.readObject();
                                    ois.close();
                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    // something SNAFU - use fall-back
                                    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                                    // configure file chooser..
                                }
                            } else {
                                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                                // configure file chooser..
                            }
                        }
                        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(showChooser);
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, showChooser);

                if (fileChooser!=null) {
                    try {
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(serializedChooser));
                        oos.writeObject(fileChooser);
                        oos.flush();
                        oos.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Correct I/O & exception handling is left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is not enough since I want the settings to persist in between the times that the application is run. I will edit the question

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I had been following advice from MSK and implementing this myself. Huge effort. Using your version and using my own we get the same results.


The folder is remembered and so is the selected file, however, the sorting by date modified and detailed view is not saved.
I really want to save sorting order and detailed view

Comment: My bad. I tested it only for retaining the current directory. :(

Comment: Thats ok. I appreciate your effort. I can extract folder and file without serialization. Serializing also saves slider position, but not the features that I am after

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I know that's example, but all streamed objects must be closed in finally block, +1

Comment: @mKorbel  Did you note my last 'not my problem' sentence?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about Object Serialization ? You can Persist the JFileChooser Object to a file and later retrieve it.

Comment: +1  That was a lot quicker way of saying what I said.  ..And sooner, as well!

Comment: I implemented serializing and tried Andrew's version. This approach saves the selected folder and selected file, but not sorting order and detailed view

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is not trivial. It should be, but it's not implemented that way. The display of the directory and the sorting is part of the LAF. The only way to get the behavior you want is by implementing your own [BasicFileChooserUI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicFileChooserUI.html), overriding `create`/`getModel` and providing an implementation of [BasicDirectoryModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicDirectoryModel.html). The sort method of BasicDirectoryModel is where the sorting is actually performed.

I've heard praise of [XFileDialog](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/), but haven't tried it myself. It's something to investigate, keeping in mind it is Windows-only (falls back to JFileChooser on OSX or Linux).

Comment: +1. i wholeheartly agree. it should be trivial. i will you suggestions when i get home.

Comment: I attempted this but I could not implement it. I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874181/java-jfilechooser-customization to keep clarity