# Java JFilechooser customization

Tags: java, jfilechooser

further to my question [Java JFilechooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859225/java-jfilechooser). It was suggested to extend  BasicFileChooserUI, overriding create/getModel and providing an implementation of BasicDirectoryModel.

I attempted this however, I could not achieve it.

JFileChooser does not have a setUI method. So your only choice is to override getUI.

```
    JFileChooser blah = new JFileChooser()
    {
        CustomFileChooserUI asdf = null;
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public FileChooserUI getUI() 
        {
            if (asdf == null)
            {
                asdf = new CustomFileChooserUI(this);
            }
            return asdf;
        }
    };
```

and

```
public class CustomFileChooserUI extends BasicFileChooserUI
{
    public CustomFileChooserUI(JFileChooser b) 
    {
        super(b);
    }

    @Override
    protected void createModel() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.createModel();
    }
}
```

but i get exceptions. Please help

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.ve.internal.java.vce.launcher.remotevm.JavaBeansLauncher.main(JavaBeansLauncher.java:86)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$BasicFileView.getName(Unknown Source)IWAV0052E Invocation Target Exception creating qwere

```
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.getName(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.setListSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.access$300(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.itemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$900(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$5.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at qwere$1.<init>(qwere.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

JFileChooser does have a setUI method to override.  JFileChooser is a subclass of JComponent which has that method.  It's signature is **setUI(ComponentUI)**.

I've updated my answer to include a simple application to show off setting a custom UI delegate for my special subclass of a file chooser.  It assumes you are running under the Windows L&F so if you are not you will need to update the subclass of the file chooser to extend the proper base UI delegate.  Avoid using BasicFileChooserUI otherwise you won't see anything.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class FileChooserUIExample extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new FileChooserUIExample();
            }
        });
    }

    public FileChooserUIExample() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Show the file chooser");
        final JFileChooser chooser = new MyCustomFileChooser();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chooser.showOpenDialog(FileChooserUIExample.this);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here's the custom file chooser class.

```
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class MyCustomFileChooser extends JFileChooser {
    public MyCustomFileChooser() {
        super();

        setUI(new CustomFileChooserUI(this));
    }


    public class CustomFileChooserUI extends WindowsFileChooserUI {
        public CustomFileChooserUI(JFileChooser b) {
            super(b);
            System.out.println("Woohoo! I'm using a custom UI delegate!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void createModel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.createModel();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ahh, I was trying to call this method (it is protected), and not trying to override it.

Comment: What diffence would single instance or all instances make?

Comment: If you set the UI delegate on only one instance of a JFileChooser only that instance will act differently.  If you want to change the behavior for any instance of JFileChooser then make sure to set the UI delegate for all of them.  Take a look at WindowsLookAndFeel.initClassDefaults to see how this is done.  There you will see a map of component UIs to UI delegates.  For the entry "FileChooserUI" you will see it maps to "WindowsFileChooserUI".  Anytime you change the L&F in your app the UI delegates will be reloaded so you should be aware of this if your app allows L&F changes dynamically.

Comment: then i want to customize a single instance. I have tried overriding setUI, but I still have exceptions. Could give me a small example

Comment: I'll write up a small example and post it here.  Give me a couple of hours though.  Day job :)